# PyQt: How to expand all children in a QTreeWidget

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4, qtreewidget

There is no real problem, I have just a cosmetic problem. Well, first I create a form with Qt Designer. On this form I place a `QTreeWidget`. We are still in Qt Designer. In `QTreeWidget`, I make a few entries (parents), and then I also take a few child entries. When I am done, I save the ui-file and then I load this file - using `loadUi()` dynamically. In this case I use PyQt4. Up to this point no problem.

When I load the form with placed `QTreeWidget` **I want the program to expand all child entries**. By default, when I run the program I only see the parent entries. When I want to see the child entries I have to click on the parent entries, but I don't want this.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an [`expandAll()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreeview.html#expandAll) method, which `QTreeWidget` inherits from the `QTreeView` class. So, after calling `loadUi()`, just add something like this:

```
  self.treewWidget.expandAll()
```